# Обработка - Выборка данных из TableView Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, tableview

Помогите разобрать только те ячейки из `TableView` в котором включены `SwitchCell`, т.е.:

```
foreach(int x in tableview.SelectedItems){ ... }
```

Код реализован вот так: XAML:

```
<TableView x:Name="tableView1" Intent="Data" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <TableRoot>
    <TableSection x:Name="LabSelection1" Title="Switches">
    </TableSection>
  </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  var cell = new SwitchCell();
  cell.Text = "Item number - " + i;
  cell.On = false;
  LabSelection1.Add(cell);
}
```

Comment: `foreach(int x in tableview.SelectedItems){ if (x.GetType() == typeof(SwitchCell)) { /* your code */ } }` - так?

Comment: @digital-mag В tableview нету параметра Selected items. Уже решил. На англоязычной версии указал решение...